# iPad: How to generate an HTML file programmatically and view it?

Tags: ipad, safari, uiwebview

I want to generate some program output and display it in Safari.

Alternatively I could display it in a UIWebView if there were a simple method for providing a Print button and then have printing occur.

Currently my approach is to save my HTML to a file, generate a full path, and then try to invoke Safari like so:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: htmlpath];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: str];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

But this is not working. Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrongly? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Apps in iOS are sandboxed, so Safari cannot access the contents of your app.

If you simply want to print it, I suggest you use a UIWebView.